# parsed gson returns null in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm new to programming,
i'm trying to get sunrise/sunset time out of yahoo weather api and toast it on Ui

(i'm using gson and anko library )
and this is my mainactivity code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fetchJson()

}

fun fetchJson(){
   val url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            toast("Failed to execute request")

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val Info = gson.fromJson(body, astronomy::class.java)


            runOnUiThread {
//                  info.sunrise is returning null ???????
                toast("this is running from UiThread ${Info.sunrise}")
            }
        }


    })
}
}
class astronomy(val sunrise: String, val sunset: String)
```

where should i fix?

Thanks

Comment: What does your Astronomy class look like?

Comment: I did it as a tutorial was, but tutorial was to parse to recycler view and mine is a single object,     this is my astronomy class.  :  class astronomy(val sunrise: String, val sunset: String)

Comment: Well, I believe that won't be enough to get sunrise/sunset time. Use: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ **to convert your Json output to POJO**. Or, get the string array by array without Gson..

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Thanks, but i want to be able change city with a textbox , ( i will edit url later )

Comment: Refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043731/kotlin-gson-fromjson-returns-null/73672368#73672368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you get back from that Yahoo! API is much larger than just the astronomy section.  You've got two options (one real option and one temporary one to check things):

- Create a number of models to parse the entire stack (meaning you'd have a `Query` class with properties like `count`, `created`, `lang`, and `results`).  This would be the better approach since you'll be dealing with real classes each step of the way.

```
data class Query(val count: Int?, val created: String?, val lang: String?, val results: Results?)

data class Results(val channel: Channel?)

//Channel should include more fields for the rest of the data
data class Channel(val astronomy: Astronomy?)

data class Astronomy(val sunrise: String?, val sunset: String?)
```

- Throw the entire string into a generic `JsonObject` (which is GSON's provided class) and traverse through that object (`query` -> `results` -> `channel` -> `astronomy` -> `sunrise` and `sunset`).  This isn't the proper approach but can work to make sure your data is coming in correctly:

```
val jsonObj: JsonObject = JsonParser().parse(body).asJsonObject

val astronomy = jsonObj
    .getAsJsonObject("query")
    .getAsJsonObject("results")
    .getAsJsonObject("channel")
    .getAsJsonObject("astronomy")

runOnUiThread {
    toast("this is running from UiThread ${astronomy.get("sunrise").asString}")
}
```

Comment: Thank dude, i wan not able to make class part work,  but get az json worked, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Hey ebrahim khoshnood!

Welcome to StackOverflow. The problem seems to be, that you haven't created POJOs (classes) for the parent objects of astronomy. If you would like to parse everything only with Gson, you will have to create objects for "query", "results", "channel" and then inside of the channel you can have the astronomy object.

So for example you could have something like this.

```
class Query(val results: List<Channel>?)
class Channel(val astronomy: astronomy?) // astronomy? is the class you have posted.
```

and then you could parse everything like this

```
val query = gson.fromJson(body, astronomy::class.java)
val astronomy = query.results?.astronomy
```